# How to unpack and unminify webpack JS file if I have script.js.map?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to unpack and unminify JS file:

```
!function(t){function e(n){if(i[n])return i[n].e
```

script.js.map:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["webpack:///webpack/bootstrap 89106cb15a44a0be8601?3322**************","webpack:///./js/....
```